# Google Bigtable export fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to use this process:
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-sequence-files
to export my Bigtable for migration.

I am using Google Cloud Shell, started off of the Google Cloud Platform dashboard.
This is Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch).
java -version reports   openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
There does not seem to be a later jre readily available (ie in apt-get) for stretch

I invoke like this:

```
java -jar bigtable-beam-import-1.3.0-shaded.jar export \
--runner=dataflow \
--project=xx-may23 \
--bigtableInstanceId=xx0523\
--bigtableTableId=test1 \
--destinationPath=gs://xx0523/test1 \
--tempLocation=gs://xx0523/tmp2 \
--maxNumWorkers=3 \
--zone=us-east4-a
```

Eventually, get this error:

```
ERROR MonitoringUtil$LoggingHandler:101 - 2018-05-26T02:10:55.387Z: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.sequencefiles.SequenceFileSink$OutputStreamWrapper.write(SequenceFileSink.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.writeFileHeader(SequenceFile.java:1145)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1214)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1091)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$BlockCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1441)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:274)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.sequencefiles.SequenceFileSink$SeqFileWriter.prepareWrite(SequenceFileSink.java:157)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$Writer.open(FileBasedSink.java:939)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteUnshardedTempFilesWithSpillingFn.processElement(WriteFiles.java:503)
```

It seems to be a java version compatibility issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like a problem from Google's side in the api. Try this instead: `curl -f -O http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigtable/bigtable-beam-import/1.2.0/bigtable-beam-import-1.2.0-shaded.jar` and continue the rest of the tutorial. If the issue is resolved, it's a google problem. If it isn't you're making a mistake somewhere following the instructions or parameters

Comment: That is helpful. Using Google Cloud Shell, I can now export from BigTable using either version 1.1.0 or 1.2.0 of the jar file.  Version 1.3.0 fails consistently.  When running repeated tests in cloud shell, I am using up-arrow key to repeat previous command and editing only the version number of the jar file and the location of the temp and export folders on my bucket.  ie, I am making only the smallest possible edits, so as not to introduce new errors.  (temp and export folders must not previously exist, per tutorial instruction, so I just bump the number up by 1 for each new test.)

Comment: Using v 1.2.0 is a good workaround for my testing.  Others may still want to know how to get v 1.3.0 working in Cloud Shell.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. I looked up version 1.2 when I suggested it and it was last edited in Feb 2018. So I assume that 1.3 is still going through some changes and errors were made. You should raise the issue on their git repo or on their jira. But glad that you raised the issue, at least their will now be some place where the issue exists :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran exactly into the same issue while following the documentation. Navigating to the maven repository, I realized there was a newer version, 1.4.0, that you can find [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigtable/bigtable-beam-import/1.4.0/bigtable-beam-import-1.4.0-shaded.jar). Invoking the new jar with the command given in the documentation went smoothly and the task succeeded.